# How do I make a DLL out of the devcon.exe source code?

Tags: c++, vb.net, dllexport

I'm working on a program that uses the enable and disable devices function of the devcon.exe. It works well but I don't think I can legally package a copy of the devcon.exe with the program. I have the source of the program, it's in C++ or C# not sure which I have no experience with and kind of C. Keeping that don't know C thing in mind; how do I make a DLL out of the devcon.exe code with only the enable and disable device functions in it? Also this DLL is for use in a vb.net program if that makes any difference. (If I need to put the entire exe into the DLL thats fine, I just thought that just having the two function in it would make it easier to make.)

devcon.exe download [here](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/311272)

devcon.exe source download [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/DevCon-Sample-4e95d71c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

devon.exe uses cfgmgr32.dll and setupapi.dll to do the actual work - instead of turning devcon.exe into a dll - use the dlls it uses instead.

To call from a 32 bit vb.net program, you need to use [pinvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx), a IJW (it just works) technology that's part of .NET that handles calling Win32 dlls from .NET by declaring a DLL import.

Most of the time, you can look on http://pinvoke.net for the proper declaration. So for example, [SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo) can be declared like:

```
Private Declare Auto Function SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo Lib "setupapi.dll" ( _
    ByVal DeviceInfoSet As Integer, _
    ByVal MemberIndex As Integer, _
    ByRef DeviceInfoData As SP_DEVINFO_DATA) As Boolean
```

The pinvoke.net entry for `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` also has an example for how to call it.

You'll have to learn the setupapi but I think that will be much easier than turning devcon.exe into a DLL, which would still require pinvoke to call.

Comment: That is awesome I had no idea those DLLs existed. Thanks a bunch! :D